# How to print in Python 3.10 a series of lists [1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, ..., n] in one liner list comprehension

Tags: python, list

I have a list `[1, 2, 3, 4, ..., n]`. In a one-liner list comprehension, how can I print the progression `[1]`, `[1, 2]`, `[1, 2, 3]`, `[1, 2, 3, 4]`, ..., `[1, 2, 3, 4, ..., n-1]`, where `n` represents an arbitrary natural number?

Comment: List comprehensions aren't supposed to be used for side effects.

Answer (score 1):

Now if you want this principle to operate on any starting list (not necessarily [1,2,...]), you can do this:

```
rawlist=['a','b','c','d']

newlist=[rawlist[:i] for i in range(1,len(rawlist)+1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
n = 10
res = [list(range(1,i)) for i in range(2,n+1)]
print(res)
```

Output:

```
[
 [1], # range(1, 2) 
 [1, 2], # range(1, 3)
 [1, 2, 3],
 [1, 2, 3, 4],
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] # range(1, 10)
]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about a for loop in a for loop?

```
n = 10

print([[x for x in range(1,i+1)] for i in range(1,n+1)])
```

This prints an array of the numbers 1 to i for each value of i in the range 1 to n.

Answer (score 0):

This should give you every list from [1] to [1,...n-1]

```
[print([x for x in range(1, y+1)]) for y in range(1, n)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting with our `[1, ..., n]` list, where `n` in this case is `5`:

```
>>> a_list = list(range(1, 6))
>>> a_list
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

we can just iterate over the list and create another list for each number, with the last one ending in `n-1`:

```
>>> print(*[list(range(1, x)) for x in a_list[1:]], sep=", ")
[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Or, doing it based on `n` directly rather than `a_list`:

```
>>> n = 5
>>> print(*[list(range(1, x)) for x in range(2, n+1)], sep=", ")
[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Note that using a list comprehension is not necessary; you can replace the outer `[]` in both examples with `()` (i.e. a parenthesized generator expression rather than a list comprehension) and it will print exactly the same thing.